# Craft beer - Ambient temperature for fermentation

Tags: style, ale, recommendations, fermentation

I am thinking about make my first beer in this summer. However, in my country the summer has an ambient temperature about 25-30º. So my question, is what type of beers are adequate to this conditions?

My first idea is a blond ale (Brewferm Ale), with fermentation at the ambient temperature in Barrel Aging. What do you think about?

Comment: Go with a Saison. That yeast likes temperatures in that range, even up to 35.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate in http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

That is really too warm as you will get fusel oils as a bi-product.  If you absolutely must do it in that high of a temperature, I would go with an ESB or something.  If you really are going to get into this, you may want to invest in an old refrigerator and maintain around 17 - 20 degrees for an ale.  Well worth the investment if you have the space and money!

Good luck.

Comment: And to embark on this route, Google "DIY Kegerator." A full-size fridge on Craigslist was only $75, and a temperature controller was about $25 IIRC. Turned out the room we were fermenting in got colder than 18 C at night in the winter, so for now I just unplug the fridge from the temp controller and plug in a desk lamp instead, which I put inside the fridge. Works like a charm.

Comment: I think you mean fusel alcohols. It depends on the yeast whether you will or not. Some strains are very tolerant of higher temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

I brew in South Florida with similar ambient temps during the spring-summer-autumn.

For beer styles, check out the saison, which enjoys a higher fermentation temperature. Wyeast 3724 has a temperature range of **70-95F, 21-35C** and [attenuates up to 80%](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp565-belgian-saison-i-yeast). I've had great success with this strain, even at the higher ends of the range.

[Beer and Wine Journal](http://beerandwinejournal.com/high-temp-yeast/) has a nice list of yeasts that do well in higher temps.

> White Labs WLP550 (Belgian Ale) — 68–78°F (20–26 °C)
>
> White Labs WLP566 (Belgian Saison II yeast) — 68–78°F (20–26 °C)
>
> White Labs WLP568 (Belgian Style Saison Ale Yeast Blend) — 70–80 °F
>   (21–27 °C)
>
> White Labs WLP065 (American Whiskey Yeast) — 75-82 °F (24–28 °C)
>
> White Labs WLP655 (Belgian Sour Mix 1) — 80-85+ °F (27–29 °C)
>
> White Labs WLP665 (Flemish Ale Blend) — 68-80°F (20 –27 °C)
>
> Wyeast 1214 (Belgian Abbey) — 68-78° F (20-24° C)
>
> Wyeast 1388 (Belgian Strong Ale) — 64-80° F (18-27° C)
>
> Wyeast 3724 (Belgian Saison) — 70-95 °F (21-35 ° C)
>
> Wyast 3725 (PC Biere de Garde) — 70-84 °F (21-29 °C)
>
> Wyeast 3763 (Roeselare Ale Blend) — 65-85 °F (18-30 °C)
>
> Wyeast 3787 (Trappist High Gravity) — 64-78 °F (18-25 °C)
>
> Wyeast 3822 (PC Belgian Dark Ale) — 65-80 °F (18-27 °C)
>
> Fermentis Safbrew T-58 — 12-25°C (54-77 °F)
>
> Fermentis Safbrew WB-06 — 12-25°C (54-77 °F)

If you're looking to bring the beer to a little bit below ambient (as fermentation is a bit of an exothermic process) try a small plastic tub full of cool water with the carboy in it wrapped in a towel. The towel will wick up cool water and evaporate, basically acting like a giant sweat gland!

Hope this helps.